# Get file name after renmaing

Tags: python

How can I get the file name after renaming it through the program?

Ex:-

0123.py

```
nw1 = input("Word?")
os.rename('0123.py',nw1)
```

After that, I want to get the name of the current file. What I have to do?

Comment: The new name is `nw1`, that's what you renamed it to.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Before asking, make sure to read some of our articles: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [writing-the-perfect-question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), [Getting answers](https://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the name of the file before it was renamed, store it in a variable beforehand:

```
name = '0123.py'
nw1 = input("Word?")
os.rename(name,nw1)

print(name)
```

Output:

```
0123.py
```

As for the final name of the file, that would be stored in `nw1`.

Comment: Sorry if I failed to ask the situation properly. Here, I want to change the name of the 0123.py file to any other word that stored in nw1. After renaming, how will I get the new filename from inside the same program? So I can use it further in a loop.

Comment: The new filename will be stored in `nw1` :)